# recyclerview child count is smaller than arrayList size in activity class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

IN my Activity class i get child of Recyclerview like:

```
final int itemsCount = recly_list_lab.getChildCount();
```

but it gave me 7 item count but i have 10 item then how to get 10 items in Main Activity

this my code for getting child item for recyclerView:

```
  final int itemsCount = recly_list_lab.getChildCount();
    Log.e("itemsCount::",itemsCount+"");
    if (itemsCount != 0) {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i <itemsCount; i++) {

                final View viewtestcategoryname = recly_list_lab.getChildAt(i);
                AutoCompleteTextView autoctv_testcategory = (AutoCompleteTextView) viewtestcategoryname.findViewById(R.id.autoctv_testcategory);
                String TestCategoryName = autoctv_testcategory.getText().toString();
                Log.e("TestCategoryname:",TestCategoryName);

                AutofitRecyclerView grid_labreferal_checkboxes_test = (AutofitRecyclerView) viewtestcategoryname.findViewById(R.id.grid_labreferal_checkboxes_test);
                final int itemcheckTestCount = grid_labreferal_checkboxes_test.getChildCount();
                Log.e("itemcheckTestCount:",itemcheckTestCount+"");

                RecyclerView recly_testsubcategory = (RecyclerView) viewtestcategoryname.findViewById(R.id.recly_testsubcategory);
                final int itemSubCategoryName = recly_testsubcategory.getChildCount();
                Log.e("itemSubCategoryName:",itemSubCategoryName+"");


                for (int test_check = 0; test_check < itemcheckTestCount; test_check++) {

                    final View viewTestCheck = grid_labreferal_checkboxes_test.getChildAt(test_check);
                    CheckBox grid_labreferal_checkbox = (CheckBox) viewTestCheck.findViewById(R.id.grid_labreferal_checkbox);
                    TextView txt_item_id = (TextView) viewTestCheck.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_id);
                    if (grid_labreferal_checkbox.isChecked()) {
                         Log.e("%sgrid_lcheckbox", grid_labreferal_checkbox.getText().toString());


                        if (txt_item_id != null && txt_item_id.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {


                        }

                    }
                }

                for (int subcatname = 0; subcatname< itemSubCategoryName; subcatname++){
                    final View SubCategory = recly_testsubcategory.getChildAt(subcatname);
                    AutoCompleteTextView autoctv_testsubcategory = (AutoCompleteTextView) SubCategory.findViewById(R.id.autoctv_testsubcategory);
                    Log.e("subcategoryname::",autoctv_testsubcategory.getText().toString());
                    AutofitRecyclerView grid_labreferal_checkboxes_subtest= (AutofitRecyclerView) SubCategory.findViewById(R.id.grid_labreferal_checkboxes_subtest);
                    final int itemcheckSubtestCount = grid_labreferal_checkboxes_subtest.getChildCount();
                    Log.e("itemcheckTestCount:",itemcheckSubtestCount+"");

                    for (int test_check = 0; test_check < itemcheckSubtestCount; test_check++) {
                        // jsonObjectMulti = new JSONObject();
                        final View viewTestCheck = grid_labreferal_checkboxes_subtest.getChildAt(test_check);
                        CheckBox grid_labreferal_checkbox = (CheckBox) viewTestCheck.findViewById(R.id.grid_labreferal_checkbox);
                        TextView txt_item_id = (TextView) viewTestCheck.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_id);
                        if (grid_labreferal_checkbox.isChecked()) {
                            Log.e("%sgrid_subtestcheckbox", grid_labreferal_checkbox.getText().toString());


                            if (txt_item_id != null && txt_item_id.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                                //testUpload.put(txt_item_id.getText().toString().trim(), grid_labreferal_checkbox.getText().toString().trim());
                            }

                        }
                    }


                }



            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share your complete code??

Comment: @sumit can you plz gave me ur email id

Comment: are u sure u having 10 items?

Comment: @sumit yes i have 10 items in my arraylist

Comment: add your code..

Comment: @Pravin i added my code plz check it

Comment: recly_list_lab.getChildCount(); instead of this try to get size from list directly

Comment: but i want to value of all recyclerview's child item.

Comment: if you have list then you have everything :)

Comment: Hi Damini why do you want your recyclerView  item count in main activity for getting it's value??

Answer (score 0):

views inside the recyler view may be less than the total number of item inside the view as views will get recycled and reused to display multiple items.

You can use adapter.getItemCount() method to know how many view item will be displayed inside recyler view.

Answer (score 0):

Not all adapter items are attached to the parent. The `getChildCount()` method returns the number of views displayed. If you want to get the item count of the adapter, you have to query the adapter for it.

```
final int itemsCount = recly_list_lab.getAdapter().getItemCount();
```

But considering your code, you're just miss-using the `RecyclerView`. You're not supposed to access child views of the recycler directly. Everything you need to do with it should go through the adapter and the view holders!

Comment: thanks for giving me ans. but if i use this method then i am not getting view and it gaves me error null pointer exception. my code is:

Comment: my adapter is not null

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView doesn't hold views for all list items in memory, it only has for example - 7 in your case. When you scroll, it reuses those 7 views for displaying different items. The purpose of this is improving the rendering performance.